# How to sort an array of objects by property value in Angular with custom pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to write a custom pipe in Angular that takes an array of objects and a variable called `order` with a value of either `ascending` or `descending` as a parameter and then sort the array of objects by a property value.

The data looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "location_type": "KAUPPA",
        "postalcode": "100",
        "availability": "LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO",
        "location": "SUOMALAINEN KIRJAKAUPPA / SISÄKÄYTÄVÄ",
        "municipality": "TURKU",
        "target_address": "ALEKSANTERINKATU 23",
        "availability_details": "",
        "coordinates_lon": "24.941095",
        "coordinates_lat": "60.168718"
    },
    {
        "location_type": "PANKIN KONTTORI",
        "postalcode": "100",
        "availability": "ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO",
        "location": "NORDEA SENAATINTORI",
        "municipality": "VANTAA",
        "target_address": "ALEKSANTERINKATU 30",
        "availability_details": "ma-su klo 06-22",
        "coordinates_lon": "24.950720",
        "coordinates_lat": "60.168930"
    },
    {
        "location_type": "TAVARATALO",
        "postalcode": "100",
        "availability": "LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO",
        "location": "STOCKMANN / 8. KERROS",
        "municipality": "HELSINKI",
        "target_address": "ALEKSANTERINKATU 52",
        "availability_details": "",
        "coordinates_lon": "24.941870",
        "coordinates_lat": "60.168430"
    }
]
```

The objects in the array need to be put into an order by `municipality`'s value.

Comment: You generally don't use pipes to do sorting https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Can I sort the data using a custom pipe at all? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Yes there is. It's well explained at the link I posted

Comment: But I dont see any cons of using pipe in such scenerios @bambam, may be I was wrong

Comment: Just read the link I've posted. Sorting is a expensive operation, and will be run multiple times per second if used as a pipe @PardeepJain

Comment: @bambam Thank you for the link, I've updated the answer as well, Please remove downvote if satisfy with the answer content else edit my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned several times in the Comments and on the above answer by Pardeep as well, using `Pipe` to sort the data is not a very good idea.

If you want to sort fields, just implement it on your template and then trigger the sort function only on events. This would significantly save you performance.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  lastSortedByField;
  ascendingOrder = true;
  data = [
    {
      "location_type": "KAUPPA",
      "postalcode": "100",
      "availability": "LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO",
      "location": "SUOMALAINEN KIRJAKAUPPA / SISÄKÄYTÄVÄ",
      "municipality": "TURKU",
      "target_address": "ALEKSANTERINKATU 23",
      "availability_details": "",
      "coordinates_lon": "24.941095",
      "coordinates_lat": "60.168718"
    },
    {
      "location_type": "PANKIN KONTTORI",
      "postalcode": "100",
      "availability": "ITSEPALVELUALUEEN AUKIOLO",
      "location": "NORDEA SENAATINTORI",
      "municipality": "VANTAA",
      "target_address": "ALEKSANTERINKATU 30",
      "availability_details": "ma-su klo 06-22",
      "coordinates_lon": "24.950720",
      "coordinates_lat": "60.168930"
    },
    {
      "location_type": "TAVARATALO",
      "postalcode": "100",
      "availability": "LIIKETILAN AUKIOLO",
      "location": "STOCKMANN / 8. KERROS",
      "municipality": "HELSINKI",
      "target_address": "ALEKSANTERINKATU 52",
      "availability_details": "",
      "coordinates_lon": "24.941870",
      "coordinates_lat": "60.168430"
    }
  ];

  sortByField(field) {
    if(this.lastSortedByField === field) {
      this.ascendingOrder = !this.ascendingOrder;
    }
    else {
      this.lastSortedByField = field;
      this.ascendingOrder = true;
    }

    if(this.ascendingOrder) {
      this.data = this.data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[field] < b[field])
          return -1;
        if (a[field] > b[field])
          return 1;
        return 0;
      });
    } else {
      this.data = this.data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[field] < b[field])
          return 1;
        if (a[field] > b[field])
          return -1;
        return 0;
      });
    }

  }

}
```

And in the Template:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td (click)="sortByField('location_type')">location_type</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('postalcode')">postalcode</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('availability')">availability</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('location')">location</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('municipality')">municipality</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('target_address')">target_address</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('availability_details')">availability_details</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('coordinates_lon')">coordinates_lon</td>
      <td (click)="sortByField('coordinates_lat')">coordinates_lat</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let datum of data">
      <td>{{ datum.location_type }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.postalcode }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.availability }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.location }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.municipality }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.target_address }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.availability_details }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.coordinates_lon }}</td>
      <td>{{ datum.coordinates_lat }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-sorting-via-field?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

> Official Docs - Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations.
>
> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself.

In general no need to use custom pipe for such case instead you can directly sort your data into your component class. But if you want to go with usage of `pipe`, refer below -

```
@Pipe({name: 'sorted'})
export class SortedPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any){
    const data =  value.sort((a,b) => a.municipality.localeCompare(b.municipality));
    return data;
  } 
}
```

[<kbd>Working example</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrsxtg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-pipe.ts)

Comment: What's wrong? why downvote, instead comment it down so that at least I could know why my answer is getting downvotes.

Comment: He wants to sort either ascending or descending. A pipe should also be reusable, so you would typically pass the property you want to access to it instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: true , agree to you point @bambam anything else I can improve in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Typesafe solution using ramda:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {prop, sortBy} from 'ramda';

@Pipe({name: 'sortBy', standalone: true})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform<T>(value: Array<T>, sortByKey: keyof T): Array<T> {
    return sortBy(prop(sortByKey))(value);
  }
}
```